# Agregate two column values from a dataframe together in one column of another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with unique gene IDs and multiple columns like this

**Table 1**

| geneID | column 1 | column 2 | column n... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | ... | ... |  |
| gene2 | ... | ... |  |
| gene3 | ... | ... |  |
| gene4 | ... | ... |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

And another dataframe with unique GO IDs with more than one gene IDs

**Table 2**

| GO_ID | Description | geneID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GO:58479 | one biological description | gene1/gene2/gene3 |
| GO:58014 | another description | gene1 |
| GO:37402 | description 3 | gene1/gene4/gene6 |
| GO:28390 | one more | gene2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I don't know if it's possible but I would like to add a new column to the table 1 with all the GO IDs and descriptions for each gene. I want just a space bar separation between ID and description but another separation like "/" or ";" between different GO IDs like this:

**Table 3**

| geneID | GO | column 1 | column n... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | GO:58479 one biological description; GO:58014 another description; GO:37402 description 3;... | ... |  |
| gene2 | GO:58479 one biological description; GO:28390 one more; ... | ... |  |
| gene3 | ... | ... |  |
| gene4 | ... | ... |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

we need miniaml and reproducible example code for answer. let's make

```
data1 = [['id1', 1], ['id2', 2], ['id3', 3]]
data2 = [['go1', 'des1', 'id1/id2/id3'], ['go2', 'des2', 'id1']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['id', 'col1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['go_id', 'des', 'id'])
```

`df1`

```
    id  col1
0   id1 1
1   id2 2
2   id3 3
```

`df2`

```
    go_id   des     id
0   go1     des1    id1/id2/id3
1   go2     des2    id1
```

---

**Code**

1st step. split df2 and explode

```
df3 = df2.assign(id=df2['id'].str.split('/')).explode('id')
```

`df3`

```
    go_id   des     id
0   go1     des1    id1
0   go1     des1    id2
0   go1     des1    id3
1   go2     des2    id1
```

2nd step. join and merge

```
out = (df3['go_id'].str.cat(df3['des'], ' ').groupby(df3['id']).agg(';'.join)
       .reset_index(name='go').merge(df1, how='right'))
```

`out`

```
    id  go                  col1
0   id1 go1 des1;go2 des2   1
1   id2 go1 des1            2
2   id3 go1 des1            3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposition with [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) :

```
out = (
        df1
          .merge(df2
                  .assign(geneID= df2["geneID"]
                                    .replace("gen", "gene ", regex=True) #read NB below
                                    .str.split("/"),
                          GO= df2[["GO_ID", "Description"]].agg(" ".join, axis=1))
                  .explode("geneID")
                  .groupby("geneID", as_index=False, sort=False)["GO"].agg("; ".join),
                 on="geneID", how="left")
          [["geneID", "GO"] + df1.columns[1:].tolist()]
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   geneID                                                                                         GO column 1 column 2  column n...
0  gene 1  GO:58479 one biological description; GO:58014 another description; GO:37402 description 3      ...      ...          NaN
1  gene 2                                     GO:58479 one biological description; GO:28390 one more      ...      ...          NaN
2  gene 3                                                        GO:58479 one biological description      ...      ...          NaN
3  gene 4                                                                     GO:37402 description 3      ...      ...          NaN
```

*NB* :
In your table2, you write (`gen1`) instead of (`gene 1`). So I'm not sure if it's a typo or not but if it's the case, remove the string replacement line.

Comment: It's an error, is exactly the same name (gene 1,...) Thank you very much for your answer!